# Centering one item horizontally in a Row in Qt

Tags: qt, qml

I am new to QML, and I would like to position one (and only one) item center in a `Row` (or `RowLayout`). As the code shown below, I want the "Hello" to be place on center(of a row) of my window.

```
    Row {
        id : titleRow
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.bottom

        topPadding: 50
        bottomPadding: 50

        Text {
            text: "Hello"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
```

I use `Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter`, but apparently it's not working. I also try `anchors.centerIn: parent`, which also failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you !

Comment: You have just one visible element here. Since you want the text centered and nothing else, I suggest you just use your `Text` element directly, and set text alignment to make it centered. If you want something more, consider replacing your `Row` with just `Item`, which will help you separate positioning it inside its parent, and positioning `Text` inside it. And then you could use actual layouts of course, but if you have just one item, then the layout might not give you much extra value.

Comment: @hyde yeah, I realize that I could just use plain `Text`'s `anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter`. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

`Row` is not a layout. It's a [Positioner](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-layouts.html). So, you cannot use `Layout.*` properties with it.

Use `RowLayout` instead.